# backward compatibility: ClassNotFoundException during deserialize object

Tags: java, serialization

For beginning - sorry for my English.

I have a class that is Serializable. The name of class is "Questions". An instance of this class is serialized and store on server as file. Then client app downloads this file and unserializes. I added some fields to it before, and everything was OK, and backward compatible.

Some time ago, I created new class. The name of this class is "Categories". I have added to my "Question" class new field with those categories.

The problem is I lost backward compatibility in this way.

When I add to "Questions" class new field that is known type (for example String) everything is OK. The problem is when I use my own, new class, that doesn't exists on client side.

Because of that during deserization it throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" exception.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How can you add a new class member to `Question` which is of a different class (that doesn't exist on the customer device) without breaking the app ? sounds like you have to update the code on the client side if you want to do it. Another (ugly) method will be to declare this variable as `Serializable` and cast it whenever you need to use it.

Comment: Hmm. I just thought Java is able to skip the data, that contains unknown class information. If this is impossible, I have a problem, but it is hard to belie, that Java developers didn't predict such situation.

Comment: It's not that they didn't predict - it's how you design your code: if you make it generic and abstract, you'll have this new class implement an interface which is recognized by other classes, and declare that variable type same as the interface. Some call it "interface programming".

Comment: When I was creating "Questions" class I couldn't predict what members I will add to it in the future.

Comment: Anyway, I tried to use Serializable (instead of Categories) as member of Qestions class. Unfortunatelly, inside Categories there is list of Category objects, and I got ClassNotFoundException for this. It looks it still tries to unserialize this member with all objects inside :(

Comment: that's how serialization works: in order for an object to be Serializable - all its members need to be Serializable as well. It wouldn't make sense otherwise. Anyways, what can you do with a class that's not there ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rely on backward compatibility, you better do not use generic serialization. Ofc its somehow possible, but i promise you you'l shoot in your knee frequently ..

Comment: I rely on it because was simply to code and, what is more important for me, it is fast for deserialize, what is important when you open half megabyte file on old Android smartphone. Using XML was 3 times slower.

Comment: then the solution is easy. don't use XML ;) use binary files. DataInputStream and DataOutputStream might be a good place to start.